# Unable to set wifi frequency/channel on Raspbian

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian

Hey I'm trying to configure my Raspberry Pi to connect to my router on channel 8 (2.447G). The WiFi network adapter I have for my Pi seems to be stuck on channel 1.

`iwlist scan` only lists the one ap near me on channel 1, my router is on 8.
`iwlist frequency` lists all 14 channels as available and that its current is 1.

I've tried `iwconfig wlan0 freq 2.447G`. It completes but running `iwconfig` still shows frequency at 2.412G

I'm using a Realtek 8188CUS adapter.

Any ideas?

Comment: please show the output of `iw phy`